# javascript global variables undefined?

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Allow me to restate my problem. These are the givens:

`main.html`

`<html>`

`<head>`

```
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/MyJS.js"></script>;`
```

`</head>`

`<body>`

`<script>`

`document.getElementById("DisplayVar").innerHTML = a;`

`</script>`

`<div id="DisplayVar">`

`</div>`

`</body>`

`<html>`

`MyJs.js`

`var a = 1;`

Nothing is displayed in the "DisplayVar" div, and the developer console says that (a) is undefined. Why is this?

Comment: have you tried `.innerHTML = window.a;` instead of just `= a;`?

Comment: Probably would be helpful to see your HTML file structure.

Comment: @AussieJoe: That won't change anything.

Comment: the answer lies in the order of your events

Comment: What is this “it” that is undefined? `document.getElementById("DisplayVar")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: you probably run MyJS.js before creating an element with id="DisplayVar". Check if it exists before assigning it's innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign innerHTML of the "DisplayVar" div after creating it

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    // or source to MyJS.js
    var a = 1;
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="DisplayVar"></div>
  <script>
    if(document.getElementById("DisplayVar"))
      document.getElementById("DisplayVar").innerHTML = a;
  </script>  
</body>
```

See [codepen](https://codepen.io/daniel-faure/pen/VxBXVO), I added a reference to an external js file, and used one of the variables defined there.

I also changed the position of the inline script. It should be placed after the creation of destination div element.

Comment: yes but the point of my question is that the variable (a) is in a separate file and that's why it isn't working. If i define (a) in `main.html` than it works just fine. I need it to work between files.

Comment: the second script cannot assign innerHTML to an element that still does not exist